# Good tutorial for Visual basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I am C++ programmer and I need to make some changes to VB6 code.

And I am looking for a good VB6 tutorial to get started.

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166138/learning-vb6). The main thing is avoiding all the information aimed at beginner programmers.

- Francesco Balena's book [Programming Visual Basic 6](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Visual-Basic-6/dp/0735605580/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1223028024&sr=8-1) is excellent and is [cheap secondhand](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=balena&sts=t&tn=programming+microsoft+visual+basic+6.0).
- Bruce McKinney's book [Hardcore Visual Basic](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/) is also excellent and free online.
- The [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314411%28VS.60%29.aspx) is really quite good. Just skip the parts aimed at beginner programmers.
- Dan Appleman's book [Developing COM/ActiveX Components With Visual Basic 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1562765760) is very good on COM/ActiveX with VB6, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you books by [Wrox Books](http://www.wrox.com) . They are written wery good and understandable.
And also there are many other programming book. Good luck in VB!)