# which book i should prefer for vb6

Tags: vb6

which book i should prefer for vb6.

and from  where i can download msdn for vb6.
if any one know any link then please share it

Comment: I believe that MS are going to be stopping support for VB6 in the not too distant future. Can I ask why you are learning VB6 instead on .Net?

Comment: Have to agree with El Ronnoco, VB6 is for all intents and purposes a "dead" language in that it'll only be used to support legacy code.

Comment: actually i am working on maintenance of a project that is in vb6.and i am not full aware of vb syntax and all.

Comment: VB6 support actually finished on April 2008 - http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/Default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=visual%20basic%206. I remember having a drink with my colleagues that evening!

Comment: MSDN for VB6 stopped shipping when Visual Studio.NET came out (sometime in late 2001)

Comment: @ashish The answers to these other questions will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166138/learning-vb6 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595737/good-tutorial-for-visual-basic-6

Comment: @El Ronnoco @Joe R @renick Those statements need some clarification. The VB6 IDE support ended in April 2008, but the VB6 runtime is [still supported and will be until at least 2018](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx). The VB6 documentation is still [on the MSDN website right now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314411%28VS.60%29.aspx) although AFAICR it has been removed from the CD/DVD version of MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember learning VB6 almost only from MSDN (and some tutorials). I had a book on very basic programming with VB. Maybe you'll find some useful stuff at http://www.vbtutor.net.

Here are two books that *seem* to be good.

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-Visual-Basic-6-0/dp/0735605580/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1285855111&sr=1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605580)

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Visual-Basic-6-0-Enhanced/dp/0619062045/ref=sr_1_13?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1285855111&sr=1-13](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0619062045)

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788229.aspx)'s the "Visual Basic 6 Resouce Center" (including links to VB6 MSDN).

Comment: I remember that Francesco Balena's book (first amazon link above) was excellent when I read it. However the whole VB6 environment is obsolete and unsupported and I doubt it will get you very far especially with Vista/Seven.

Comment: +1 Balena's book is excellent and well done for providing the link to MSDN.

Comment: @renick You're right that the Balena book is excellent. The IDE is unsupported, however people do [get it running on Vista and Windows 7](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/columns/article.aspx?editorialsid=2257). If the worst comes to the worst you can always run the IDE in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Basic 6 bible is:

[Visual Basic 6 from the ground up](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0078825083)

And you can still buy the software via Amazon for $40:

[Visual Basic 6, Learner edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002SFK8)